# Type 'URL' has no member 'fileURL' - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, url, swift3

In Swift 2, I had used the following code:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Document", ofType: "pdf")!
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
```

Now, using Xcode 8 and Swift 3, Xcode automatically translated it to:

```
let path = Bundle.main.pathForResource("Translation", ofType: "pdf")!
let url = URL.fileURL(withPath: path)
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))
```

On the second line, with the declaration of `url`, Xcode gives me the following error:

> Type 'URL' has no member 'fileURL'

How can I fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Actually the proper syntax for line two in Swift 2 is `let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)` (although the class method seems to work), that's why the translation failed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `URL` struct in Swift 3 has an initializer for that

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do not use `path` later, you can write something like this:

```
let url = Bundle.main.urlForResource("Translation", withExtension: "pdf")
```

Comment: path property will always be available to your url if `url.isFileURL` is true, just check it to know if `url.path` is suitable for input into FileManager.